# Compare elements of a matrix by java columns

Tags: java, matrix

I have the following code and the following doubt about the route of the column of a matrix, comparing with the previous one, later and others. I take the first column from top to bottom. I take the first element and compare if they are the same as the next one (below). This second position of the column, compares if they are the same with the one above and the one below, and so on with the third one. I mean, if I have this column:

```
1
2
2
2
3
2
2
2
2
1
```

If you have 3 or more identical contiguous numbers, I have to set them to 0 (that's what I think it would do). The output would be:

```
1
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
0
1
```

This I need to do with each column, I have this method and I want to do it in the simplest way, the most direct solution without strange things, although I'm thinking that it has to be recursive anyway, I do not know. The only thing that makes me is to create a matrix of zeros and I can not find the fault.

**Code:**

```
 public static void matrix(int[][] matrix, int size, int[] color, int position) {

int repeated = 0;
for (int row  = 1; row < size; row ++) {
    for (int col = 1; col < size; col++) {
        if (matrix[row][col] == matrix[row][col++]) {
            repeated = matrix[row][col];
        }
        while (matrix[row][col] == repeated) {
            matrix[row][col] = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code working?, What is output with this code?

Comment: It does not do well. It makes a column of zeros, another one of numbers . It does not look if it has equals or if not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I constructed for your scenario.  You can find helpful comments within the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  int matrix[][] = new int[][]{
      {1,2},
      {2,2},
      {2,2},
      {2,2},
      {3,2},
      {2,2},
      {2,2},
      {2,3},
      {2,1},
      {1,3}};
  matrix(matrix, 10, null, 0);
  System.out.println(matrix);
}

public static void matrix(int[][] matrix, int size, int[] color, int position) {
  //This value keeps track of the current value checked for repetition
  int repeated = 0;
  //The running total for repeated
  int count = 1;
  //My matrix create with 2 columns,
  for (int col  = 0; col < 2; col ++) {
    //initialized - may need length check
    repeated = matrix[0][col];
    count = 1;
    for (int row = 1; row < size; row++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] == repeated)
      {
        count++;
      }
      else
      {
        //reset the values when match fails
        count = 1;
        repeated = matrix[row][col];
      }
      if(count == 3)
      {
        //First score of 3
        matrix[row][col] = 0;
        matrix[row-1][col] = 0;
        matrix[row-2][col] = 0;
      }
      else if(count > 3)
      {//Scoring after 3
        matrix[row][col] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output

[[1, 0],

[0, 0],

[0, 0],

[0, 0],

[3, 0],

[0, 0],

[0, 0],

[0, 3],

[0, 1],

[1, 3]]